# BorderThickness of TextBox in WPF (a bug?)

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have noticed a strange behaviour of TextBox while `BorderThickness` property is set to 1 - the focus causes the border to change the color (to something like white). 
However, if I set the border thickness to something different than 1, say .99 or 1.01 the problem disappears.

Is it the bug in WPF? Or is it intended?

Comment: What is your video adapter's DPI set to?  Does SnapToDevicePixels have an effect?

Comment: I think I'm able to reproduce this. If you have a TextBox and it gets focus, then the border changes color. However, if the BorderThickness is something else than "1", this doesn't happend. Never seen this, don't think I've ever set the BorderThickness of a TextBox before. (+1)

Comment: @Hans, I think SnapToDevicePixels doesn't have any reasonable effect. The problems occurs only if TextBox gets the key focus (i.e. one is writing and the mouse is moved over the TextBox).

Comment: I dunno, it is normal for the border color to change when the control gets or loses the focus.  It shifts between a bluish and a grayish tint on my machine.  This does *not* happen when the border width value has a fraction.  Show a screenshot if it is different on your machine.  And *do* document the DPI setting.

Comment: @Hans, why the color does not change if the border width has a fraction?

Comment: I have changed the value to 2 - the border does not change the color. So, it changes only for 1...

Comment: Hmya, that's the implementation detail that WPF tries to ignore and/or deal with.  There are no fractional pixels on a monitor.  That's why I asked about SnapToDevicePixels.  Very hard problem as long as monitors have crappy DPI values.  Resolution independent graphics was first tried in GDI+.  Harsh reception.

Comment: @Hans, but anyway, is there any possibility to disable changing the border color with the thickness set to 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior of the Aero style for TextBoxes. To disable it you would need to restyle the TextBox. You can take the default styles from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972144%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) (see Download Sample).

In the default Style for TextBoxBase (which TextBox is based on), you will see it uses a ListBoxChrome. This element is defined in the Presentation.Aero assembly and is responsible for rendering the "focused" look. You can simply remove the RenderFocus setting and possibly the RenderMouseOver, or replace it with a Border.

Then you'd want to include that in your application resources.

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TextBoxBorder"
      StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,20" MappingMode="Absolute">
  <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
      <GradientStop Color="#ABADB3" Offset="0.05" />
      <GradientStop Color="#E2E3EA" Offset="0.07" />
      <GradientStop Color="#E3E9EF" Offset="1" />
  </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBoxBase}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}" BasedOn="{x:Null}">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" />
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorder}" />
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
  <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
              <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                      SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                  <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
              </Border >
              <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                  <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                      <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />
                      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                  </Trigger>
              </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBoxBase}}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"/>
```

If you look at the ListBoxChrome class in Reflector (specifically the OnRender method), you can see it will only render the focused look if it's BorderThickness is "1,1,1,1".